Why are the lines crisscrossing Europa dark colored
Jupiter's moon Europa is crisscrossed by dark lines. If Europa's surface is made of ice what causes the lines dark color?

They are called lineae. From Wikipedia:

Europa's most striking surface features are a series of dark streaks crisscrossing the entire globe, called lineae (English: lines). The larger bands are more than 20 km (12 mi) across, often with dark, diffuse outer edges, regular striations, and a central band of lighter material.
The most likely hypothesis is that the lineae on Europa were produced by a series of eruptions of warm ice as Europa's crust slowly spreads open to expose warmer layers beneath. The effect would have been similar to that seen on Earth's oceanic ridges. These various fractures are thought to have been caused in large part by the tidal flexing exerted by Jupiter. Because Europa is tidally locked to Jupiter, and therefore always maintains approximately the same orientation towards Jupiter, the stress patterns should form a distinctive and predictable pattern

Some also hypothesize that the lines are the salt from underground sea. See ref. 3 for more details.
More articles for viewing:

https://europa.nasa.gov/resources/88/dark-bands-on-europa
https://sci.esa.int/web/juice/-/59915-blood-red-scars-and-veins-on-europa
https://www.space.com/29392-jupiter-moon-europa-salty-dark-streaks.html


So the dark lines may be caused by salt being bombarded with radiation.
